# using a method parameter as placeholder(Sorry for my bad grammar btw)

Tags: java

I have two methods with the same name, but with different parameters:

```
public void calculate(double waveLength){
//......
}
public void calculate(double freq, double not){
//......
}
```

I want to add one more, but it also needs only two double parameters. So i did this:

```
public void calculate(double E, double not, int placeholder ){
//.....
}
```

Where 'placeholder' use is to differenciate this method from the others, but i feel like this is not the right way to do it. My question is: is there any better of doing it?

Comment: My first thought is that "calculate" is very abstract term, is it possible perhaps to make the method names more specific, such as calculateXXX() and calculateYYY(), which may result in having fewer overloaded implementations of the same method?

Comment: `calculateSomeMeaningfulNameWhichHelpsExplainTheParameters(double e, double not)` - not always pretty, but sometimes required

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I think "calculate" is a very generic method name and does not make it easy for the user/caller to understand what the method is doing.

I would recommend choosing names such as calculateThis(), and calculateThat() (random choices, replace it with something meaningful to the caller and future readers of your code). That should lead to fewer overloaded methods and better code readability/maintainability.